# Parameterized testing with 2 arguments in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize("x", [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("y", [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
def test_foo(x, y):
 pass
```

How I can set a range for "x" and "y", like as x[0-16] and y[0-10]

Comment: Was there a specific problem with using range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) builtin for that one. Example below:

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize("x", range(17))
@pytest.mark.parametrize("y", range(11))
def test_foo(x, y):
 pass
```

You then change the numbers above based your specific range exclusive of that number (i.e., 0 - 16 for `range(17)`)

Comment: Now I want to run that code with "my_test.exe --my_command x y". How I can do it?

Comment: You'll need to ask a different question for that, but you can put in params in your pytest code. That's a different attack altogether :)